# FlexGet: RSS parsing and check rating from kinopoisk

Tags: python, download, automation, rss, torrent

I want:

1. get rss-feed with movies list from torrent

   nnm-club.me/forum/rss.php?f=218&t=1
2. parse of description field and get kinopoisk-link with 'kinopoisk_id' (analog imdb) from this description:

   www.kinopoisk.ru/film/**kinopoisk_id**/
3. get rating of movie from kinopoisk by 'kinopoisk_id':

   kinopoisk.ru/rating/**kinopoisk-id**.xml
4. if rating of movie >= 7.0, send torrent to my trasmission;
5. ignore movies without rating and movies that flexget downloaded (by kinopoisk_id).

Help me please.

---

I got kinopoisk_id:

```
tasks:
  nnm-club:
    rss:
      url: http://nnm-club.me/forum/rss.php?f=218&t=1
      other_fields: [description]
      ascii: yes
    manipulate:
      - kinopoisk_id:
          from: description
          replace:
            regexp: '(.|\n)*http://www.kinopoisk.ru/film/([0-9]+)/(.|\n)*'
            format: '\2'
```

How do I request a rating?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wrote a plugin `kinopoisk` for FlexGet to this task:

https://gist.github.com/danilvalov/720966d26e99f06aed41